# who or whom for subject of the passive sentence

Tags: relative-pronouns

> Joe who had been invited comes to party.
>
> Joe whom had been invited comes to party.

Which relative pronoun is suitable, who or whom for subject of the passive sentence.

Answer (score 3):

That relative clause needs to be non-restrictive, that is, set off by commas:

> Joe, who had been invited, came to the party.

Please notice the change of tense. If you want to use present for the main verb, the subordinate could be in the present perfect (to indicate a past event with present results):

> Joe, who has been invited, is coming to the party.

"whom" is always object, so it has to be followed by a word other than a verb. If what follows is a verb, use "who":

> Joe, **who had** been invited, came to the party.
>
> Joe, **whom they** had invited, came to the party.

Answer (score 1):

Joe is the subject, even in the passive form, therefore *who* applies.